# Drawing and audio not working together in Java Android App

Tags: java, android, audio

I am currenty doing a small game. But my application does not work properly. Program does not stop with error, but firstly it playes part of track, and after that (around 5-10 seconds) it stops and drawing begins.

Without audio added, code works absolutely fine.

I also tested app on several different devices and emulators, but issue keeps occuring.

Here are some methods from class "Game.java", where I am trying to implement audio.

```java
public class Game {
    Plane background;
    Plane playfield;
    Context context;
    List<SingleNote> notes = new ArrayList<SingleNote>();
    List<SingleNote> notes_to_compute = new ArrayList<SingleNote>();
    Date date = new Date();
    long time_initial;
    float[] touch_coord = new float[2];
    private int mStreamId;

    public Game(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public void load(){
        background = new Plane(context, R.raw.vertex_shader, R.raw.fragment_shader, R.drawable._map1);
        playfield = new Plane(context, R.raw.vertex_shader, R.raw.fragment_shader, R.drawable.s_playfield);
        InitNotes(R.raw._map1);
        time_initial = date.getTime();
        MyThread m = new MyThread();
        m.context = context;
        m.start();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public void draw(){
        background.draw();
        playfield.draw();
        update();
    }
}


class MyThread extends Thread {
    Context context;
    public void run(){
        SoundManagement.playSoundPool(context, R.raw._map1_a);
    }
}
```

And static PlaySondPool method in class

```java
    public static void playSoundPool(Context context, int soundID) {
        int MAX_STREAMS = 20;
        int REPEAT = 0;
        SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, REPEAT);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int soundId, int status) {
                int priority = 0;
                int repeat = 0;
                float rate = 1.f; // Frequency Rate can be from .5 to 2.0
                // Set volume
                AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float streamVolumeCurrent =
                        mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float streamVolumeMax =
                        mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;
                // Play it
                soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, priority, repeat, rate);
            }
        });
        soundPool.load(context, soundID, 1);
    }
```

I thought using separate thread would help, but same issue occurs.
What should I do in order to avoid this error? Maybe use another library, or play sound from other class?

Whole code here: https://github.com/arthur100500/AndroidProject

Additional debug ingormation from android studio

Logcat: https://pastebin.com/MQSaWw8R

Run: https://pastebin.com/5D4AGuHZ

How it looks: https://youtu.be/X7IBquHs1jA

Comment: Does this behavior also happen on a more current, more powerful Android device? I hear the sounds breaking up which is often an indication that memory is being overtaxed. JELLY_BEAN is old and is about to be deprecated, and the device you are using might not be up to the task. Also it would be helpful to know: for how long is the cue is supposed to play?

Comment: I tested it on several phones, on Bluestacks and android emulator. Version is not old on an emulator, it is just minimal required

Comment: Good to know. And the length of the cue?

Comment: If I understood right my music file is about 5 minutes long

Answer (score 1):

I think there is every likelihood that the choice of `SoundPool` for playback is the source of the problem you are experiencing. `SoundPool` is designed for the handling of audio files that are short (a couple seconds) and can be held in memory. You've indicated that you are trying to use it to play a 5-minute long file. According to [the documentation in the API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), only the first MB of the 5-minute file is being handled.

> Soundpool sounds are expected to be short as they are predecoded into
> memory. Each decoded sound is internally limited to one megabyte
> storage, which represents approximately 5.6 seconds at 44.1kHz stereo
> (the duration is proportionally longer at lower sample rates or a
> channel mask of mono). A decoded audio sound will be truncated if it
> would exceed the per-sound one megabyte storage space.

Streaming via an [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) should be a more fitting alternative for this sound file.

> An AudioTrack instance can operate under two modes: static or
> streaming. In Streaming mode, the application writes a continuous
> stream of data to the AudioTrack, using one of the write() methods.
> These are blocking and return when the data has been transferred from
> the Java layer to the native layer and queued for playback. The
> streaming mode is most useful when playing blocks of audio data that
> for instance are:
>
> - too big to fit in memory because of the duration of the sound to play,
> - too big to fit in memory because of the characteristics of the audio data (high sampling rate, bits per sample ...)
> - received or generated while previously queued audio is playing.

Comment: I tested it with sinwave in beginning just like i started with Soundpool. First 10-15 seconds it lagged a lot. And after it worked just fine. I think my app is loading resources, ad during this time it does not work.